# Most efficient way to construct similarity matrix

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matrix, scipy

I'm using the following links to create a "Euclidean Similarity Matrix" (that I convert to a DataFrame). 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53068/euclidean-distance-score-and-similarity
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html

The way I'm doing it is an iterative approach which works but it takes a while when the datasets are big. The pandas pd.DataFrame.corr() is really fast and useful for pearson correlations.

**How can I perform a Euclidean Similarity measure w/o exhaustive iteration?**

My naive code below:

```
#Euclidean Similarity

#Create DataFrame
DF_var = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"s1":[1.2,3.4,10.2],"s2":[1.4,3.1,10.7],"s3":[2.1,3.7,11.3],"s4":[1.5,3.2,10.9]}).T
DF_var.columns = ["g1","g2","g3"]
#      g1   g2    g3
# s1  1.2  3.4  10.2
# s2  1.4  3.1  10.7
# s3  2.1  3.7  11.3
# s4  1.5  3.2  10.9

#Create empty matrix to fill
M_euclid = np.zeros((DF_var.shape[1],DF_var.shape[1]))

#Iterate through DataFrame columns to measure euclidean distance
for i in range(DF_var.shape[1]):
    u = DF_var[DF_var.columns[i]]
    for j in range(DF_var.shape[1]):
        v = DF_var[DF_var.columns[j]]
        #Euclidean distance -> Euclidean similarity
        M_euclid[i,j] = (1/(1+sp.spatial.distance.euclidean(u,v)))
DF_euclid = pd.DataFrame(M_euclid,columns=DF_var.columns,index=DF_var.columns)

#           g1        g2        g3
# g1  1.000000  0.215963  0.051408
# g2  0.215963  1.000000  0.063021
# g3  0.051408  0.063021  1.000000
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two useful function within `scipy.spatial.distance` that you can use for this: [`pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) and [`squareform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html#scipy.spatial.distance.squareform).  Using `pdist` will give you the pairwise distance between observations as a one-dimensional array, and `squareform` will convert this to a distance matrix.

One catch is that `pdist` uses distance measures by default, and not similarity, so you'll need to manually specify your similarity function. Judging by the commented output in your code, your DataFrame is also not in the orientation `pdist` expects, so I've undone the transpose you did in your code.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean, pdist, squareform


def similarity_func(u, v):
    return 1/(1+euclidean(u,v))

DF_var = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"s1":[1.2,3.4,10.2],"s2":[1.4,3.1,10.7],"s3":[2.1,3.7,11.3],"s4":[1.5,3.2,10.9]})
DF_var.index = ["g1","g2","g3"]

dists = pdist(DF_var, similarity_func)
DF_euclid = pd.DataFrame(squareform(dists), columns=DF_var.index, index=DF_var.index)
```

Comment: Hey @root, thanks for clarifying the use of pdist and squareform!  Why is the diagonal matrix 0.0 after the similarity function?

Comment: Note! The  diagonal can be fixed with the comment in Kevin's answer from @B.M.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just use `pdist` and [`squareform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) to broadcast directly on your DataFrame:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist,squareform

In [6]: squareform(pdist(DF_var, metric='euclidean'))

Out[6]:
array([[ 0.        ,  0.6164414 ,  1.4525839 ,  0.78740079],
       [ 0.6164414 ,  0.        ,  1.1       ,  0.24494897],
       [ 1.4525839 ,  1.1       ,  0.        ,  0.87749644],
       [ 0.78740079,  0.24494897,  0.87749644,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Transpose first : In [247]: 1/(1+squareform(pdist(DF_var.T)))
Out[247]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.21596281,  0.05140761],
       [ 0.21596281,  1.        ,  0.06302091],
       [ 0.05140761,  0.06302091,  1.        ]])

Answer (score 2):

You want `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` or `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can find to get the same result as the OP is to use [distance_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html), also from scipy.spatial. The whole thing can be done in one sort-of-long line.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

# Original code from OP, slightly reformatted
DF_var = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "s1":[1.2,3.4,10.2],
    "s2":[1.4,3.1,10.7],
    "s3":[2.1,3.7,11.3],
    "s4":[1.5,3.2,10.9]
}).T
DF_var.columns = ["g1","g2","g3"]

# Whole similarity algorithm in one line
df_euclid = pd.DataFrame(
    1 / (1 + distance_matrix(DF_var.T, DF_var.T)),
    columns=DF_var.columns, index=DF_var.columns
)

#           g1        g2        g3
# g1  1.000000  0.215963  0.051408
# g2  0.215963  1.000000  0.063021
# g3  0.051408  0.063021  1.000000
```

The code above should copy-paste and run in any python IDE.

Comment: How would you compute the cosine distance / similarity with your method?

Comment: @moritz - This solution uses a function that's explicitly for Euclidean distance, which I use a lot. Possibly, scipy.spatial.distance.cosine (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html) would do what you want. But I haven't used or tested it. You should try it out and ask a new question if just replacing the distance_matrix function with distance.cosine doesn't work out.

Comment: The OP asked for a similarity matrix, not a distance matrix, so you should also include the bit to convert the distances to similarities.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

DF_var = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"s1":[1.2,3.4,10.2],"s2":[1.4,3.1,10.7],"s3":[2.1,3.7,11.3],"s4":[1.5,3.2,10.9]}).T
DF_var.columns = ["g1","g2","g3"]

def m_euclid(v1, v2):
    return (1/(1 + euclidean(v1,v2)))

dist_list = []
for j1 in DF_var.columns:
    dist_list.append([m_euclid(DF_var[j1], DF_var[j2]) for j2 in DF_var.columns])

dist_matrix = pd.DataFrame(dist_list)
```